# Visual Studio Code fecha arquivo sozinho

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-code

No Visual Studio Code quanto eu abro um arquivo e logo em seguida eu abro outro arquivo que vou trabalhar ele fecha automaticamente o primeiro arquivo aberto. Como faço para impedir isso?

Comment: Já tentou olhar nos logs de eventos do Windows qual a causa do fechamento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez você esteja abrindo o arquivo somente em modo de **preview/visualização** e não de edição. Para tornar a *tab* fixa sem fechar, tente verificar isso. Em contra partida, você pode entrar em configurações/ferramentas e ajustar "Tabs and Windows", que seriam as abas e janelas no seu **Visual Studio**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Show!! Era isso mesmo. Na verdade como estou usando o Visual Studio Code eu fui em File > Preferences > User Settings e adicionei a linha "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false

Comment: @FelipeCoelho Que bom que deu certo! Precisar, dê um grito aqui! Abs.

Comment: @viana, obrigado! deu certinho!